# How to set a Limit on Bulk Collect with a Nested Table PL/SQL Collection?

Tags: oracle, plsql, nested-table, bulk-collect, rowtype

I'm trying to set a limit on a database query with the limit keyword.

This is my current working query without the limit keyword.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NESTED_TABLE_DECLARATION IS TABLE OF SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
   NESTED_TABLE NESTED_TABLE_DECLARATION;
BEGIN
   SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO NESTED_TABLE FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME;
END;
/
```

I want to avoid using a cursor but still use the limit keyword like below.

```
DECLARE
   TYPE NESTED_TABLE_DECLARATION IS TABLE OF SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME%ROWTYPE;
   NESTED_TABLE NESTED_TABLE_DECLARATION;
BEGIN
   SELECT * BULK COLLECT LIMIT 100 INTO NESTED_TABLE FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME;
END;
/
```

Comment: What  version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Is your intention that you're only ever going to get 100 rows from this query?  If so, do you care which 100 rows you get or are you fine with any arbitrary 100 rows?

Comment: Why don't you want to define a cursor?

Comment: @ BobJarvis: 12.1

@ JustinCave: For future performance tuning I want to be able to change this number quickly. The table may contain 10000 records in some setups in others over a million.

@ APC: I might need to use a dblink and cursors can't be passed over dblinks.

Comment: What is the reason for such a limitation?

Comment: Every SELECT defines a (implicit) cursor, so your statement is not clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to use the reserved word Limit in your main query, this only works using a cursor for the bulk collection to optimize the memory of your server. In your case, use **Rownum < 100** in the **Where**.

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO NESTED_TABLE FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME WHERE rownum <= 1000;
```

Or Oracle12c

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO NESTED_TABLE FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Can you add example of this?